# editing css files through php

Tags: php

my head was spinning over this idea for a long time . and i though this is the right plce to ask for help ..
so what i want to do is make a really simple php file that make a search and replace in css files but the problem that i have is that a single css file can (as you all know ) have a 100 or more background tags and all i want to edit is one of them .. and what is some body added a line before or after ... so search and replace for the whole section of the css file that i want to replace well be useless unless it is all the same ..
i really have a bad time explanning but i hope that you get the main idea ..
all i want is some guidelines in this .. help is really appreciated/

Comment: This is **not** a real answer to your question, but instead of using php to change a stylesheet, you just might want to use e.g. [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) as your stylesheet language. It's based on CSS (it eventually produces CSS code) but you have the ability to declare variables and methods, which makes it a bit more "dynamic".

Comment: In the words of Homer Simpson: when something is hard to do, is probably not worth doing :) It's just not meant to be used like that.

Comment: lol thanks .. this might have been the best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest directly editing a linked CSS file through PHP (file_get_contents()) or something, but rather conditionally link different CSS files. Or perhaps, conditionally change what you need to change through CSS directly in HTML with PHP. For example, need to change background (for some reason) for different users, you would conditionally change the image source through PHP.

Comment: hmmm.. so what im asking for is nearly impossible or what .. 
and please dont get me wrong i want some ideas i dont want nobody to write the code for me .. thanks for the help

Comment: It is not impossible, you can get CSS data with file_get_contents() and use preg_replace(). But it might be too complicated for what you're trying to accomplish. However it will be too messy, and will take a long time to run. Just imagine, every user who clicks on your site, this script will run (with a slow REGEX function) and bog down the host. Not even that, you're constantly editing the CSS file, and if by chance (not that small), two users access the CSS file at the same time while it is being rewritten, it will cause a page not to load.

Comment: thanks .. maybe this is not an answer .. and i know that i can do what i want but i might end up with a huge class but why not i'll try .. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly do you want to do this? Maybe a CSS alternative like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) is a viable option (it has support for variables etc)

Comment: i want to modify a php script that i have right now .. and it uses css files

Answer (score 0):

You can either use php to load a [stylesheet.php](http://davidwalsh.name/css-variables-php-dynamic) that is dynamically generated or use javascript to "compile" it on the client side (like [LessCss](http://lesscss.org/))